# How is Ember handling this controller .property()

Tags: ember.js

I am displaying a list of `Document` titles on the site's sidebar area. To achieve this I created a `documents` property on the `App.SidebarController`

```
Document = require '../models/document'

SidebarController = Ember.Controller.extend
  documents: (->
    Document.find()
  ).property()

module.exports = SidebarController
```

This works fine, when I create a new `Document` in my application, this sidebar property get's updated automatically and I don't know why. It works no matter what I put in the `.property()` function. e.g.

```
.property('Document')
.property('App.Document')
```

Can somebody explain how this works? What would be the correct thing for the `property()` function to observe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are basically saying that is works, but you would like to know why.

**Here is my guess:** When your controller gets rendered, your computed property gets computed for the first time and an instance of an array is returned. When you create a new Document, **i think this very same array is updated (= Document is added).** So it does work despite the fact, that you do not specify a dependent key on property(). This is because the right array is already in place. As i said just a guess, but this seems like an understandable explanation.

**And what would be the correct thing to do?**
IMHO one should not use such Data Access methods directly in a computed property. Instead you should call this Data Access method inside a Route and then assign it to the controller. This way you make sure, that the find() method gets executed when needed.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the answer! I agree about having a route setup data for the controller, the problem is my sidebar isn't a route, it's just called via `{{render 'sidebar}}` in the `application` template - so I'm only working with a `controller` / `view`. I don't know how I would trigger all the stuff that happens when you direct to `/#/documents` (the route that sets up the documents) from the sidebar.

Comment: @mavilein is right about how/why things are working, and that data access methods should be in a route. Since you are calling `{{render}}` from the `application` template, use `ApplicationRoute.setupController()` hook to set things up.